# By async="async" tag in javascript sometimes my JS files have 'undefined is not a function' Why ? How to force some how Sequence between them?

Tags: javascript, html

I use the following code to load my JavaScript files. which works fine for me

```
<script  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script  src="../js/jq/jquery.ui.core.js" ></script>
<script  src="../js/jq/jquery.ui.widget.js" ></script>
<script  src="../js/jq/jquery.ui.mouse.js" ></script>
<script  src="../js/jq/jquery.ui.mouse1.js" ></script>
<script  src="../js/jq/jquery.ui.mouse2.js" ></script>
<script  src="../js/MyLoader.js" ></script>
```

but when I change it into the following code And add **async="async"** to script.

```
<script  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" async="async"></script>
<script  src="../js/jq/jquery.ui.core.js" async="async"></script>
<script  src="../js/jq/jquery.ui.widget.js" async="async"></script>
<script  src="../js/jq/jquery.ui.mouse.js" async="async"></script>
<script  src="../js/jq/jquery.ui.mouse1.js" async="async"></script>
<script  src="../js/jq/jquery.ui.mouse2.js" async="async"></script>
<script  src="../js/MyLoader.js" async="async"></script>
```

It has strange behavior sometimes all javascript files loading sometime some javascript files are missing .

I check this in Chrome.
*According to Documentation It has to be load but Asynchronously not or badly loading ??
The most important thing for me is to force MyLoader.js load as the last javascript then it can use the resources in the other libarary. So Question is how to delay one JS file to load as last javascript file ??*

example of erorr in broswer

```
query.ui.mouse.js:20Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'widget'
jquery.ui.widget.js:67Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
jquery.ui.widget.js:67Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
loader.js:6Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'draggable'
2event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the main problem you are trying to solve is to make sure that `MyLoader.js` is loaded last and that everything else is loaded before it, then simply remove the `async` attribute from all your script tags.  The browser will then load and execute them in the order encountered in the file.

---

For more info on using async, you cannot make multiple JS files that depend upon each other and must be loaded in a specific order all be async.  They may then load in the wrong order and cause errors.

For example, all the jQuery.ui files depend upon jquery.min.js so it MUST be loaded first.  When you load things async, their order is no longer guaranteed so you are rolling the dice on whether they will be loaded in the correct order or not.

The best candidates for async loading are scripts that don't depend upon any other async scripts, scripts that aren't required for the initial rendering of the page and scripts that somewhat stand on their own.  They do their own work when they load and the timing of when that work is done is not critical or coupled with anything else in the page.  A perfect example of such a script is a script that records web statistics on a remote server.  It isn't involved in the initial rendering of the page, it doesn't matter if it happens right when the page is loaded or a second or two later and it isn't couple with anything else in the page.

See [this article](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/12/27/coupling-async-scripts/) for some good discussion of the topic.

If you really wanted to load a bunch of dependent scripts async and load them in a specific order, then you would have to use a bunch of additional code to coordinate that.  That level of order and coordination will not happen automatically with the async attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Your question right now sounds like: How can I load scripts in order asynchronously? :) The real answer is that you don't need `async` in there. Newer browsers download scripts in parallel an execute them in order

Comment: I use HTML5 , Do I need to load them Async so be little faster ?

Comment: No, that's what my answer says. Async may cause it to be executed out of order. With newer browsers, async doesn't make it faster, since they do parallel downloads (but in order execution) anyway

Comment: @Emax - async allows your page to render before a script is loaded.  The penalty for that is that there is no defined order in which async scripts will load.  See my answer for what types of scripts can best be loaded async (hint, it's not what you have).

Comment: @jfriend00: If you want the HTML to render before the scripts are requested, just put the scripts after the HTML, http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_5/

Comment: I'm well aware of the benefits of putting scripts after the content.  async goes even further than that as the page can be fully live and free for the user to interact with it before async scripts are loaded.   That is not the case with a script placed at the end of the body.

Comment: @jfriend00: Correct, if your files do not need to be loaded in order, than at the top with async is a better solution. But if they do need to be loaded in order, I think the only thing you can do is move it to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

This should be quite simple to fix, just concatenate all the jquery js files into a main file and then load that (this also saves on URL requests and makes the page load faster)

OR

Check if the functions in jquery are defined before executing them

```
typeof func!=="undefined"
```

Comment: Combining all your files into one is not always a good idea since browsers now download files in parallel. Therefore, 3 200K files is better than one 600K file.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `defer` for scripts that have dependency. `defer` is the same as `async` except it maintain the executing order. More info here: http://www.webkit.org/blog/1395/running-scripts-in-webkit/

Answer (score 0):

Async tag means that will load asynchronous.

So if `jquery.min.js` still loading when his dependences start to be loades, the script will not work.

If you want to load async, try work with AMD pattern, I personaly recomend [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)